# Send alert box if controller doesn´t found results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Controller` like this:

```
public string GetTareasCalendario(TareaModel model) {
    var tareas = ag.ConsultarAgenda(model);

    var eventos = new {
        Asignados = new List < TareaCalendarioModel > (),
        NoAsignados = new List < TareaCalendarioModel > ()
    };

    foreach(var x in tareas) {
        //some code there
    };

    if (x.FechaInicioTarea != null && x.FechaFinTarea != null) {
        eventos.Asignados.Add(tareaCalendario);
    } else {
        eventos.NoAsignados.Add(tareaCalendario);
    }
}

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    eventos,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });
}
```

this is executed with Ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/Agenda/GetTareasCalendario/",
    data: {
        //Some data there
        ....
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (eventos) {
        refreshCalendarEvents(eventos.asignados);
        addEvents(eventos.noAsignados, true);
    }, error: function () {
        alert('Something is wrong, please try again.');
    }
```

but now I want to know how to set message if I have 0 results of my query. As you can see I have error into ajax, but how can I set something if I have zero results? Regards

As Yamamoto comment I try to use:

```
if (!$.trim(eventos.length === 0)) {
    alert("No results found");
}
```

But it just don´t pass to alert box in debug[image]

Results of console.log(eventos)[image]

Comment: Try using `if (!$.trim(eventos)) { alert("Results are empty") }`, or check with `eventos.length == 0` in `success` part.

Comment: You say in success function right? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Right, you need to check in `success: function (eventos)` part, since `error` part only executes if the request returns HTTP 4XX status code.

Comment: It doesn´t work :( @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Can you provide contents of `eventos` using `console.log(eventos)` when the query returns 0 results? Seems that you need to check something exists inside JSON string instead of its length.

Comment: I upload photo of what occurs there. And relative controller events @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Try one of the following: `if (eventos.asignados === []) { ... }`, `if ($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados)) { ... }`, `if (!$.isArray(eventos.asignados) || !event.asignados.length)) { ... }` or `if (eventos.asignados.length == 0) { ... }`. Perhaps `isEmptyObject` is the best way to check empty array in either `asignados` or `noAsignados`.

Comment: It works using isEmptyObject thanks! @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you want to check empty array presence in `eventos.asignados`, you need to use [`$.isEmptyObject`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) in `success` function part like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Agenda/GetTareasCalendario/",
        data: {

          //Some data there
           ....
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (eventos) {
            if ($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados && eventos.noAsignados)) {
                alert("No results found");
            } 
            else {
                refreshCalendarEvents(eventos.asignados);
                addEvents(eventos.noAsignados, true);
            }
        }, error: function () {
            alert('Something is wrong, please try again.');
        }
});
```

NB: The same check with if-condition can apply to `eventos.noAsignados` as well (edit: both of them can be combined in a single if-condition).

Comment: I combine two as: `if ($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados && eventos.noAsignados)) {...}`

Comment: I have an issue there, can you helo me ?

Answer (score 0):

It works now as @Tetsuya Yamamoto comment I use

```
($.isEmptyObject(eventos.asignados))
{ 
alert('No values recevied from controller')
}
```